# Solving a non-linear, transient system of pde's (reaction-diffusion)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of PDEs with non-linear terms:

$\frac{\partial a(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } a(x,y,z,t)  h(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial b(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } b(x,y,z,t) i(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1$ } e(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial c(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } c(x,y,z,t) g(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1$ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial d(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } a(x,y,z,t) h(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial e(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } b(x,y,z,t) i(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } e(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial f(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } c(x,y,z,t) g(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial g(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} {\nabla^2} g(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3$ } a(x,y,z,t)-\frac{g(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial h(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} {\nabla^2} h(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3$ } b(x,y,z,t)-\frac{h(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial i(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} {\nabla^2}i(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3 $ } c(x,y,z,t)-\frac{i(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } e(x,y,z,t)$

with non-linear terms in $\color{red}{red}$ and spatial terms in $\color{blue}{blue}$, constants $\tau_1$,$\tau_2$,$\tau_3$,$\tau_4$, $\mathscr{D}$ and with the laplace opaterator written as $\nabla^2$

with initial conditions:

$a(x,y,z,0)=\sqrt{\frac{40}{\pi}}\mathscr{e}^{-40((x+\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2+z^2)}$

$b(x,y,z,0)=\sqrt{\frac{40}{\pi}}\mathscr{e}^{-40(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

$c(x,y,z,0)=\sqrt{\frac{40}{\pi}}\mathscr{e}^{-40((x-\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2+z^2)}$

(where $\mathscr{e}$ is eulers number). the rest is zero at t=0

in a unit sphere with natural Neumann conditions

My main questions is which software should I use and which method I should use to solve this problem.
My go to standard software, Mathematica ([which apparently does not support nonlinear constants, see my Mathematica post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/151087/edit) and Matlab (where pdenonlin does not have a time dependent solution) do not seem to do this.

I am now looking into the deal.ii nonlinear solving where they again seem to iterate to get the stationary solution. Since I am interested in the oscillatory behavior of my system this will not do. Is it intrinsic in the method to solve nonlinear pde's that this will solve for a stationary solution?

Comment: What does $\mathscr{D}$ denote?

Comment: it is a constant (a diffusion constant to be exact)

Comment: Got it; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been browsing a bit, and this seems like the perfect starting point for me: https://fenicsproject.org/pub/tutorial/html/._ftut1010.html